# cant parse json response, its actually not empty yet returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this json codes which I used from sending a post request and retrieving data and then parse it (refer below).

```
$.ajax({
       url: '/test',
       type: 'post',
       data: { id : "1"},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(response){
           if(response.success){
               console.log(JSON.stringify(response.disputeRecord));
                $.each(response.disputeRecord, function(index, value){
                   alert(value.creation_date);

                });
           }
       }
    });
```

and this is the json contents of the "response.disputeRecord" (a view from a console)

```
{"no":7,"employee_id":"MMMFLB003","creation_date":"2015-07-09","log_date":"2015-06-25","log_type":"LOGGED","dispute_time":"07:00","reason":"No Logout data","effect":"Update Logout Data","status":"HR APPROVED","authorized_person":"MMMFLB003","authorized_reason":"You have it","mngmt_updated_at":"2015-07-09 03:12:12","hr_approver":"MMMFLB003","hr_approver_reason":"Approve Dispute Request","hr_updated_at":"2015-07-09 03:13:01"}
```

as you can see, im trying to alert the "creation_date" which actually exist on the json response but it gives me "undefined", any ideas, clues?

Comment: response.disputeRecord is not an array, so $.each wont do what you think

Comment: try my answer it alerts the date, as needed

Comment: @JaromandaX: so any suggestion to parse it ?

Comment: alert(response.disputeRecord.creation_date); will do the trick, remove the $.each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
$.each(response.disputeRecord, function(index, value){
    if (index == "creation_date")
        alert(value);
});
```

index is the property name and value is the property value, so you need to check which property and then alert its value.

http://jsfiddle.net/44z83jpn/

or simply access the property directy from the object and remove the $.each:

```
if(response.success){
    alert(response.disputeRecord.creation_date)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j0vL9f05/

Comment: Why parse all the properties for one with a specific name, when you can just reference it directly?

Comment: Not sure how it would ever be of benefit to parse all the properties when he's specifically looking for just 1.

Comment: Well good now he knows how $.each works :-), part of the journey mate

Answer (score 2):

The example above shows that you're not getting an array of `disputeRecord` - just one.  In that case, the `each()` is confusing the issue as there is nothing to parse.  Try this instead...

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/test',
   type: 'post',
   data: { id : "1"},
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response){
       if(response.success){
           console.log(JSON.stringify(response.disputeRecord));
           console.log(response.disputeRecord.creation_date);
       }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$.each` on an object, not an array. The `index` argument is actually going to be your object's property names and `value` is going to be the corresponding property value. You're going to get `("no", 7)`, `("employee_id", "MMMFLB003")` and so on.